# Dojo Tree : bridge from *unformatted* json to expected format

Tags: dojo

I am very new to Dojo (1.7), and I am very excited by the AMD loader and the global philosophy, then thought I have red some dozen of documentation and googled a lot and my brains starts to grill, I am still unable to understand and perform some things : I would like to display a dijit.Tree of *any* sort of JSON, yes like a JSON editor, because I use also persistent JSON files for storing few datas (not only for GET/.../ transmission) . Here are my expects :

- sample JSON : `{"infos":{"address":"my address","phone":"my
  phone"},"insurance":{"forks":[14,53,123],"prices":[5,8,"3%"]}}`
- display the differents variables of any JSON : the root child is the
  root json variable, children L1 are the root variables, etc...and upon the json variable type (String, Number, Object, Array) I will also display a corresponding icon
- not to have to parse the whole json and format it in one big time, would like for exemple to display first the root node, then the well formated children trought a getChildren method for example, so it is done progressively on expando (like a lazy load). I have already made my own Trees classes with javascript, the more flexible way was I gave a dataRoot, a renderItem(dataItem, domItem) and a getChildren(dataItem) to the constructor so I could perform and return all I want, the Tree only performed the rendering  only when needed, the Tree had no knowing about datas structure neither modify it, but I am not sure to understand well why the dijit.Tree needs a so restrictive way of build...

Here is my last try, it might totally not the right way, (maybe I have to subclass) but as far as I understand, I need to play with 3 classes (dojo store, tree model and tree widget), but firstly it seems the model can't get the root node, please check my different code comments. So please is there any patient person that can give me a simple example with some clear explanations (yeah I am a bit demanding), at least the list of the right necessary variables for constructor's options I need for start displaying a nice tree view of my json file, there's so much I'm totally lost, many thanks !

```
...
// before there is the AMD part that load the needed things
Xhr.get({ url:'data/file.json', handleAs:'json',
    load: function(data){
        console.log('xhr.loaded : ', data);// got my javascript object from the json string
        var store = new ItemFileReadStore({// is it the right store I need ??
            // or the Memory store ?
            // assuming later I'll need to save the data changes 
            rootId : 'root',// 
            rootLabel : 'Archive',// useless ? isn't it the model responsability ?
            data : {id:'root', items:[data]}// trying to give a root node well formatted
        });
        var model = new TreeStoreModel({
            store : store,
            getChildren : function(obj){
                // firstly here it seems the root is not found
                // I got a 'error loading root' error
                // what is missing in my instanciations ??
                // what is exactyly the type of the 1st arg : a store ?
                console.log('getChildren : ', this.get(obj.id));
            },
            mayHaveChildren : function(){
                console.log('mayHaveChildren ', arguments);
                return true;
            }
        });
        var tree = new Tree({
            model: model
        }, domId);
        tree.startup();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution is based on `dojo/store/Memory` inspired by [Connecting a Store to a Tree](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/store_driven_tree/):

[image]

You can find live demo at http://egoworx.com/ or download complete source from [dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2131149/tree.zip).

Now code. First `dojo/store/Memory`:

```
var data =  {"infos":{"address":"my address","phone":"my phone", "gift": false, "now": new Date()},"insurance":{"forks":[14,53,123],"prices":[5,8,"3%"]}};

var store = new Memory({

  data: data,

  mayHaveChildren: function(object) {
    var type = this.getType(object);
    return (type == "Object" || type == "Array");
  },

  getChildren: function(object, onComplete, onError) {
    var item = this.getData(object);
    var type = this.getType(object);
    var children = [];

    switch(type) {
      case "Array":
        children = item;
        break;
      case "Object":
        for (i in item) {
          children.push({label: i, data: item[i]});
        }
        break;
    }
    onComplete(children);
  },

  getRoot: function(onItem, onError) {
    onItem(this.data);
  },

  getLabel: function(object) {
    var label = object.label || object + "";
    var type = this.getType(object);

    switch(type) {
      case "Number":
      case "String":
      case "Boolean":
      case "Date":
        var data = this.getData(object);
        if (data != label) {
          label += ": " + this.getData(object);
        }
    }

    return label;
  },

  getData: function(object) {
    if (object && (object.data || object.data === false) && object.label) {
      return object.data;
    }
    return object;
  },

  getType: function(object) {
    var item = this.getData(object);
    if (lang.isObject(item)) {
      if (lang.isArray(item)) return "Array";
      if (lang.isFunction(item)) return "Function";
      if (item instanceof Date) return "Date";
      return "Object";
    }

    if (lang.isString(item)) return "String";
    if (item === true || item === false) return "Boolean";
    return "Number";
  },

  getIconClass: function(object, opened) {
    return this.getType(object);
  }    
});
```

Please note I added a *boolean* and *Date* type to your data.

`dijit/Tree` based on this store:

```
var tree = new Tree({
    model: store,
    persist: false,
    showRoot: false,
    getIconClass: function(object, opened) {
      if (lang.isFunction(this.model.getIconClass)) {
        return this.model.getIconClass(object, opened);
      }
      return (!item || this.model.mayHaveChildren(item)) ? (opened ? "dijitFolderOpened" : "dijitFolderClosed") : "dijitLeaf";
    }
  }, "placeholder");

tree.startup();
```

And finally a stylesheet to display data type icons:

```
.dijitTreeIcon {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;  
}

.Object {
  background-image: url(http://dojotoolkit.org/api/css/icons/16x16/object.png);
}

.Array {
  background-image: url(http://dojotoolkit.org/api/css/icons/16x16/array.png);
}

.Date {
  background-image: url(http://dojotoolkit.org/api/css/icons/16x16/date.png);
}

.Boolean {
  background-image: url(http://dojotoolkit.org/api/css/icons/16x16/boolean.png);
}

.String {
  background-image: url(http://dojotoolkit.org/api/css/icons/16x16/string.png);
}

.Number {
  background-image: url(http://dojotoolkit.org/api/css/icons/16x16/number.png);
}
```

I cannot access jsFiddle since I'm currently in China, but I'll put the code above there upon my return to Europe and post a link here.

Comment: hey man THAT looks pretty good !!! finally someone show me the way I expected (trought model.getChildren so it is progressive, no having to make a whole json copy so not heavy), I thought my question was a little ugly. I begun to be a little discouraged by Dojo. Let me test it a bit one day, but as far as the demo and the clear and complete code you provided, I'll give you the points, it worth it ! many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try somethign like that instead :

```
store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                url : "",
                data: {
                    identifier: "id",
                    label   : "label",
                    items   : [{
                        id      : "root",
                        label   : "root",
                        type    : "root",
                        children: [data]
                    }]
                }
            });
```

Also in general avoid overriding the tree functions, you might extend them, but becareful.
If you want to console.log, then rather connect to them...

ItemFileReadStore is a read-only store, so not the one you want for "saving modifications".
You can try the ItemFileWriteStore, or JsonRest, etc.

Comment: thank you, effectively the doc mentions that this is the items.children that will be considered as the root node. But I still have the "error loading root", I just set the store as you wrote, I removed my getChildren and hasChildren overwrite, but no way to get it...I am preparing a jsfiddle...

Comment: here is a condensed jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mr5En/1/
give "error loading root"...

Comment: Hello : check this http://jsfiddle.net/mr5En/3/

in general, remember that ItemFileWriteStore and ItemFileReadStore do not use json structures, but array like structures. So it did not really like the infos and insurance objects in the middle. Adding them through newItem solves the problem because the store convert the json object to an array like structure. If you can use a rest server, then maybe try using the JsonRest, or JsonRestStore instead :)

Comment: hello, well that's approaching what I am looking for : a bridge from unformated to store expected format. But I thought it could be done with model getChildren where I could return children from my unformated datas, not to have re-build a whole store copy of a json file. I understand the store conception (data uniformization) but I actually don't need it, because I am trying to edit and save a whole javascript object to json at once, not CRUD operations. Well I think it is quite heavy and it is quite hard with dojo to know wich class is better or not for our needs...

Comment: I think I have to do much more tests with dojo before going further, but thank you for your time, I understand few things better thanks to your sample.

Comment: You are welcome :) Good luck! And if you need more help, do not hesitate coming on irc freenode #dojo :)

Comment: ok sure ;) ! because I am very excited by the AMD loader (I made mine with head.js and Mootools wich manage dependencies also) but it needs more work to understand well...